# Display a tooltip on CPTPlotSymbol when hover it

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I'm working with Core Plot to draw a scatter plot. It works fine. But I would like to display the current value when hover a CPTPlotSymbol. Please see the following picture :
[image]

**Here's a sample code :**

```
- (void)configurePlots
{
[...]
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [myPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    myPlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    symbolLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
    CPTPlotSymbol *symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];
    symbol.lineStyle = symbolLineStyle;
    symbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    myPlot.plotSymbol = symbol;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display any additional information when you touch the bar/point you should implement

```
    -(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
}
```

or

```
-(void)scatterPlot:(CPScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:    (NSUInteger)index
{
}
```

delegate method (depend on chart type). Don't forget set up a delegate.